# Is the PHP directive entry 'register_globals' has been completely removed from the php.ini(The PHP configuration file) as of PHP 7.1.12?

Tags: php, directive, php-7, php-ini, register-globals

I'm using **PHP 7.1.12** using **XAMPP** on **Windows 10** operating system.

Today, I was just checking the output of `phpinfo()` in my web browser and surprisingly I no where found an entry for the directive `register_globals` in it.

Almost on 70% of its pages, the PHP Manual mentions this directive `register_globals` has been deprecated and should not be used but I can't even see the respective entry in **php.ini** file. So, is the respective entry has been completely removed from the PHP distribution?

Also, let me know whether old `$HTTP_*_VARS` arrays are accessible to me i.e. in **PHP 7.1.12** or not or they also have been removed from the PHP distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*register_globals* has been removed around PHP5.4, you an still simulate the behaviour but it is a **bad practice**.

You can emulate its behavior by adding a function call to a user-written *register_globals()* function like this:
https://pageconfig.com/post/register_globals-is-back-php-implementation

Or by prepending a user-written script to every executed php files, like this:
http://www.kaffeetalk.de/using-register_globals-in-php-5-5/

$HTTP_GET_VARS is called simply $_GET now, same for $*POST, and most of the old $HTTP**_VARS has new names as well, most of the time it will only take a simple replace in path to migrate, but otherwise the whole structure got removed in PHP5.4:
http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.useful.php